# 500 internal server error

Tags: troubleshooting, 500-internal-error

I am facing 500.0 Internal server quite frequently with my website.

The error details are given below.

```
HTTP Error 500.0 - Internal Server Error
C:\PHP\php-cgi.exe - The FastCGI process exceeded configured activity timeout

Module  FastCgiModule
Notification    ExecuteRequestHandler
Handler PHP_via_FastCGI
Error Code  0x80070102
Requested URL   http://mydomain.com:80/index.php
Physical Path   C:\HostingSpaces\coderefl\mydomain.com\wwwroot\index.php
Logon Method    Anonymous
Logon User  Anonymous
```

When I contacted the support team, they're saying that my site is making heavy SQL Queries. I am not sure how to debug this. But my site is very small and the database is optimized. I'm running wordpress as platform. How to resolve this issue.

Comment: what is your permalink structure?.. heavy sql queries can often be associated with custom permalinks that can hammer resources

Comment: It's in the format domain.com/Year/Month/Date/Title-of-the-blog-post

A sample URL would be like this (
http://codereflect.com/2011/06/08/software-is-free-but-the-service/ )

Comment: What Plugins do you have installed/active?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your site codereflect.com is not that heavy. Could be the Suffusion theme and its options making lots of DB calls. I'd use http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/debug-queries/ to see what queries are being called and how many. And it also could be you're on a shared box at softlayer that is "too" shared with others.

Comment: Thank you. I actually called the technical support team and scolded them like anything as my part is clear. The changed my blog's application pool at their server now it seems work fine.